# Search on svn for files with same propertie value

Tags: svn

How could i search on my repositoryfor all files using the same propertie value? i believe that i could use [svn propget](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html) or [svn proplist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.proplist.html)  on a working copy, but what if i want to search for the propertie value directly on the repository?  For example if i have 3 files with the propertie project_id = 12345 How could i search for then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Propget work with URL as target, but can't internally filter and show only *some of* properties:

`svn pg project_id URL/OF/REPO -r -v` will show all objects with `project_id` defined